Making DFF required based on Conditions
In Oracle apps r12, Is there any way to make some DFF fields mandatory based on certain condition.
For instance, In Sales Order form I have 2 DFF,
Field1 and its value is Yes
Field2
So, when the Field1 value is Yes, Field2 should be required.
I tried to achieve using form personalization, But I won't be able to capture the event for DFF fields.

This should be possible using context-sensitive segments and a context field.  Although some more complex versions of this may not display the same on OAF.
See Planning Your Descriptive Flexfield in the Oracle E-Business Suite Flexfields Guide.

How can I reference DFF field in Context? Both fields are DFF fields and based on first DFF field value the second DFF field should be required.

I believe you need to do it via a displayed context field - you need to define a context field with an appropriate value set. Associate a DFF segment to that field. Specify that segment is required based on the context field.
